# Cron jobs run twice (CentOS6.5)

Tags: cron, centos, x86-64, centos6.5, pstree

I noticed that logwatch output from 1 of my servers is emailed twice. After giving a deeper look to the thing, I found out that it's not only the logwatch, but all the cron jobs simply run twice.

Yesterday I spend some hours on research, but did not get to an answer yet.

So, in order to avoid answers or assumptions which I already analysed:

No, cron daemon is not running twice (ps ax)

No, I don't have duplicates in /etc/crontab and /var/spool/*

When I run `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly' manually, it runs just once, as expected.

I tried creating a test script in cron.hourly (1echo) and wait for the cron to run. 
Here's the contents of the `1echo' script:

```
date >> /var/log/mycron.log
pstree >> /var/log/mycron.log
```

And here's what I have logged in the `mycron.log' file:

```
Wed Oct  8 11:01:01 AMT 2014
Wed Oct  8 11:01:01 AMT 2014
init-+-crond---2*[crond---run-parts-+-awk]
     |                              `-run-parts---pstree]
init-+-crond-+-crond---run-parts-+-awk
     |       |                   `-run-parts---pstree
     |       `-crond---run-parts
```

It's seen from the contents of the log, that the task is run twice at the very same time: first both runs log the date and then the outputs of the pftrees follow.

The /etc/crontab file is the system default, so I do not paste it here.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see if you type `crontab -l`?

Comment: It is empty for all users, i.e. there's no file in /var/spool/cron at all.